# How can I run this simple for loop in parallel bash?

Tags: r, bash, parallel-processing, slurm

I am trying to run an Rscript multiple times with different parameters and I am using a bash script to do so (I got an error while trying to run it in parallel in R with things like foreach and doParallel but that is not the problem here).

My script, which I intended to call with `$sbatch script.sh` (on a hpc) looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my@mail.com

cd my_dir

for a in 1 2
do
for b in 1 2 3 4
do
for c in 1 2 3
do
for d in 1 2 3 4
do
for e in 5 10 15 20 30 40 50 75 100 200 300 400 500 750 1000 1250 1500 1750 2000
do
Rscript /hpc/someRscript.R $dist $rlen $trans $meta $init &
done
done
done
done
done

echo done
```

The command `$sbatch script.sh` results in me getting an email after about 40 seconds, telling me its done. I suspect using the & sign is the wrongdoer here. I think it is trying to do everything at the same time, which would overload the compute node.

Is there an easy way to turn this into an array job? Or is there a better way for me to run this in parallel?

Comment: If you're looking to limit parallel operations (eg, based on available resources) then you may want to look at a) `GNU parallel`, b) `xargs / -P`, or c) roll your own code by manually counting the number of jobs kicked off in the background plus the use of `wait -n`; a google search on any of these items should bring up quite a few hits on stackoverflow (or its sister sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your script to work, you need to

1. either use variables names `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. or `$dist` `$rlen` `$trans` `$meta` `$init` but not both
2. end the scrip with `wait` otherwise Slurm will think your script has finished

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my@mail.com

cd my_dir

for dist in 1 2
do
for rlen in 1 2 3 4
do
for trans in 1 2 3
do
for meta in 1 2 3 4
do
for init in 5 10 15 20 30 40 50 75 100 200 300 400 500 750 1000 1250 1500 1750 2000
do
Rscript /hpc/someRscript.R $dist $rlen $trans $meta $init &
done
done
done
done
done
wait
echo done
```

Now one issue is that this will create 1824 processes and try to run them all at the same time. This will be highly inefficient. So you should use `srun` to "micro-schedule" all theses processes on the available number of CPUs. Note that you might need to explicitly request a certain amount of CPUs with `--ntasks`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my@mail.com
#SBATCH --ntasks=<SOME NUMBER>

cd my_dir

for dist in 1 2
do
for rlen in 1 2 3 4
do
for trans in 1 2 3
do
for meta in 1 2 3 4
do
for init in 5 10 15 20 30 40 50 75 100 200 300 400 500 750 1000 1250 1500 1750 2000
do
srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive Rscript /hpc/someRscript.R $dist $rlen $trans $meta $init &
done
done
done
done
done
wait
echo done
```

Furthermore, if GNU Parallel is available, you can simplify the script as

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my@mail.com
#SBATCH --ntasks=<SOME NUMBER>

cd my_dir

parallel -P SLURM_NTASKS srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive Rscript /hpc/someRscript.R ::: 1 2 ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: 1 2 3 ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: 5 10 15 20 30 40 50 75 100 200 300 400 500 750 1000 1250 1500 1750 2000

echo done
```

Transforming this into a job array is not trivial. One small step is to take the innermost loop for instance (the largest) and run the array over that parameter

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=10G
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=my@mail.com
#SBATCH --ntasks=<SOME NUMBER>
#SBATCH --array=0-18

cd my_dir

INIT=(5 10 15 20 30 40 50 75 100 200 300 400 500 750 1000 1250 1500 1750 2000)

parallel -P SLURM_NTASKS srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive Rscript /hpc/someRscript.R {} ${INIT[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} ::: 1 2 ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: 1 2 3 ::: 1 2 3 4 

echo done
```

You can run the array over all combinations provided you create them all in a Bash array and use the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` to index them.